# The "awaitModalSubmit" method does not work properly (Undefined)! || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
async function createTicketModal(interaction, ticketType) {
      if (interaction.deferred || interaction.replied) {
        // Interaction has already been replied to or deferred
        return;
      }
    
      const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('ticketModal')
        .setTitle(`${ticketType} - Ticket`);
    
      const questionModal = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('questionModal')
        .setLabel('Please describe your problem.')
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);
    
      const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(questionModal);
    
      modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);
    
      const modalMessage = await interaction.showModal(modal);
    
      try {
        const modalResponse = await modalMessage.awaitModalSubmit({
          filter: (interaction) =>
            interaction.customId === 'ticketModal' && interaction.user.id === interaction.user.id,
          time: 60000,
        });
    
        if (modalResponse.isMessageComponent()) {
          const description = modalResponse.values[0];
    
          const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`${interaction.user.username}-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            //parent: 'PUT_YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_HERE', // Replace with the ID of the category you want to create the ticket channel in
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guild.id,
                deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
              },
            ],
          });
    
          if (!channel.isText()) {
            await modalMessage.editReply({
              content: `Failed to create a text channel for your ${ticketType} ticket.`,
              embeds: [],
              components: [],
            });
            return;
          }
    
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`${ticketType} Ticket`)
            .setDescription(`Problem Description: ${description}`)
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .build();
    
          await channel.send(`${interaction.user}`, { embeds: [embed] });
    
          // Close the modal by updating the interaction with an empty array of components
          await modalMessage.editReply({ components: [] });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await modalMessage.editReply({
          content: `An error occurred while creating your ${ticketType} ticket. Please try again later.`,
          embeds: [],
          components: [],
        });
      }
    }
```

When running the command (`/ticket`) the bot sends an embed message with 4 buttons. When clicking on one of the buttons it must show a modal asking *'Please describe your problem'*. But the problem is when I click on one of the buttons it returns an error in the console/terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'awaitModalSubmit')
    at createTicketModal (C:\---\Commands\Info\ticket-sys.js:90:50)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\---\Commands\Info\ticket-sys.js:48:15)
C:\---\Commands\Info\ticket-sys.js:136
        await modalMessage.editReply({
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editReply')
    at createTicketModal (C:\---\Commands\Info\ticket-sys.js:136:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\---\Commands\Info\ticket-sys.js:48:15)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

### NOTE:

I used to have a collector but I replaced it with the `awaitModalSubmit` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`showModal`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=showModal) doesn't return anything, so `modalMessage` is `undefined`. [`awaitModalSubmit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=awaitModalSubmit) is available on `CommandInteraction` so something like the snippet below should work. Also, you shouldn't use the same variable name (`interaction`) inside your filter as `interaction.user.id === interaction.user.id` won't work.

```js
await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
  filter: (i) =>
    i.customId === "ticketModal" &&
    i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
  time: 60000,
});
```

Comment: It works but now the modal says `Something went wrong! Try again!`

Comment: I'll look into it soon. I see there is a new question with this; if I find the issue, I'll post an answer there.

Comment: The "new question" is posted by me. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941068/problems-with-discord-js-modal-something-went-wrong-try-again-discord-js).